# Как убрать знак вопроса после домена?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, поисковые-системы, индексация, http-status-code-301

Здравствуйте. Был сайт на CMS, сейчас без нее, но в поисковых системах остались старые ссылки. Большинство профиксил, осталась ссылка вида `www.domain.com/?`. И при переходе на эту страницу открывается главная страница, но в Яндекс Вебмастере её видит как дубль главной страницы. Хочу сделать переадресацию ссылок вида `www.domain.com/?` и `www.domain.com/?[цифры]` на главную страницу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
RewriteEngine On
# в строке HTTP-запроса отлавливаем запрос вида /?\d*
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?\d*\ HTTP/
# и делаем редирект на корень сайта с удалением GET переменных (знак вопроса ОБЯЗАТЕЛЕН)
RewriteRule ^ http://your.site/? [R=301,L]
```